# Regex for userid validation

Tags: regex

I know I should study up on regex but quite frankly, I only need to write one every third blue moon.  Today is that 3rd blue moon.

Looking for a regex that will validate the following userid in javascript:

```
AA1234 or     
aa1234 or    
aa123a or    
aa123A or    
any other combination of capital or lower case letters.
```

If I were to put this in words, it would be spelled out like 2 letters, 3 digits, followed by a letter or a digit.

Can someone help me with this today?

Per comment below, updated request for JavaScript

Comment: Matching letters and digits is literally the first thing you'll learn in a regex tutorial. Why don't you give it a try? It's not that bad, I promise. =)

Comment: And regexes are sometimes different depending on the base language. Your question should tell which one you care about.

Comment: @DavidCain See, had you not replied, I wouldn't have known that was one of the first things to learn.  I'll give it a shot.  Thanks.

Comment: @DavidCain Blackbear provided a link which includes a quick reference.  I was able to follow the reference and his solution and between you and his link, I'm ready to try a tutorial.  I'm sure w3schools has a tutorial but do you have a better source?

Comment: [Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info) has a [tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) that's worth trying. Honestly, I learned Vim's regular expression syntax from `:help pattern`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're pretty easy actually, it took me half an hour to learn the basics.

Here's your regex anyways:

```
[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{3}[a-zA-Z0-9]{1}
```

See it at work [here](http://rubular.com/r/RxDaWOY0XY).

Comment: That rubular links is awesome!  Thank you!

Comment: still have a few minutes before I can accept it.

Comment: I thought I'd be able to limit this to only 6 characters by entering [[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{3}[a-zA-Z0-9]{1}]{6} but that didn't do it.  I'll review this on my own but just wanted to let you know I'm trying.  :D  Thanks again.

Comment: @dlackey great, trying is the best way ;) good luck :)

Comment: Here is the pattern I ended up going with since I know the IDs will never be more than 6 characters `/\b[A-Z]{2}\d{3}[A-Z0-9]{1}\b/i;`

Comment: @dlackey seems reasonable, but beware that it will only capture capital ids

Comment: the /i in JavaScript makes it case insensitive - or so I though.

Comment: @dlackey good point, you're learning well :P

Answer (score 0):

`[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{3}[a-z|A-Z|0-9]{1}`

Simplest is this. But cross yourself that you will understand this and use it.

Comment: Here is the pattern I ended up using:  `/\b[A-Z]{2}\d{3}[A-Z0-9]{1}\b/i;`